# My remainder IPhone application getting delayed in seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I have made a remainder application using `UIDatePicker` and `NSLocalNotification`. The remainder app is ready and is working, but the remainder gets triggered some seconds later each time.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)addRemainder
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateform=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateform.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateform stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    date=[dateform dateFromString:formattedDate];
    str=[dateform stringFromDate:date];

    if(textField1.text!=nil)
    {

        notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.fireDate = date;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.alertBody = textField1.text;
        notification.alertAction=@"Show me the item";
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        NSUInteger nextBadgeNumber = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]    scheduledLocalNotifications] count] + 1;
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = nextBadgeNumber;
        notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    }

    if ([remainderr isEqualToString:@"edit"])
    {
        [remainder replaceObjectAtIndex:([index integerValue]) withObject:textField1.text];
        [TimeDate replaceObjectAtIndex:([index integerValue]) withObject: str];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your problem will be on NSDateFormatter since you have added seconds in it it will return the seconds too. hence there will be seconds delay.

Change your NSDateFormatter to

`@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"`

Explanation:

LocalNotification will be set to the format  @"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS" so we haveto convert it to the format  @"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm" (Without seconds).